# using sed within a while loop

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use sed within the script to replace all , with spaces for the output of MyGROUP

MYGROUP=

```
for group in ${MYGROUP/,/ /} ; do
    case $group in
        cars) MY_GROUPS="$MY_GROUPS,red" ;;
        bikes) MY_GROUPS="$MY_GROUPS,blue" ;;
    esac
done
MYGROUP=${MY_GROUPS#,}
```

so i need when the result is red,blue to be red blue

Comment: Can we assume that `MYGROUP='cars,bikes'`?  Would it be ok to suggest using arrays instead? What were you intending to use `sed` for?

Comment: @Kusalananda i am using the sed to replace the , with a space so that it will be MYGROUP=cars bikes
As later on in the script it uses those variables

Comment: why use ```sed``` when ```${MYGROUP/,/ }``` does the same?

Comment: @noAnton because that makes it comma seperated

Comment: Welcome! Could yoy post the expected result with real input data?